# How to get previous month values in UTC in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, utc

I need to use jquery flot plugin to plot time based data on a graph in a web page. It needs time parameters to be passed in UTC format. Getting current date is quite easy just defining a Date Object help. But i also want the UTC value for last six months from current date how to get that in JS..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at link : [Jquery Date](https://github.com/1Marc/jquery-date)

Comment: Link by itself is not an answer.

Comment: Thanks...!! was able to get the required values.